# cloudbees jenkins build ioexception2

Tags: ios, jenkins, hudson, ioexception, cloudbees

I am building iOS project, using cloudbees, Jenkins continuous integration.

This project I have already up and running on my local Jenkins just fine. So I have imported the job, provisioning profiles, keychain and setup everithing as on my localhost.

The only difference is that I have selected "osx" as a Label Expression of running enviroment. (since cloudbees are using multiple build platforms) and I cannot even start the building process.

Output:

```
Building remotely on 51e861e6 in workspace /scratch/jenkins/workspace/TestFlight
Checkout:TestFlight / /scratch/jenkins/workspace/TestFlight - hudson.remoting.Channel@1b27f122:51e861e6
Using strategy: Default
hudson.util.IOException2: remote file operation failed: /scratch/jenkins/workspace/TestFlight at hudson.remoting.Channel@1b27f122:51e861e6
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:907)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:884)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.determineRevisionToBuild(GitSCM.java:942)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1108)
at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1411)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:662)
at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:571)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1665)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:246)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Remote call on 51e861e6 failed
at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:748)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:900)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to load hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM
at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader.loadClassFile(RemoteClassLoader.java:326)
at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader.findClass(RemoteClassLoader.java:236)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2348)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1916)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getDeclaredSUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:1622)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$700(ObjectStreamClass.java:51)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:433)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:421)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:318)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:555)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1601)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1496)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1750)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1970)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1895)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1777)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.deserialize(UserRequest.java:182)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:98)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)
at     hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/plugins/git/GitSCMBackwardCompatibility
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:471)
at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader.loadClassFile(RemoteClassLoader.java:322)
... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.plugins.git.GitSCMBackwardCompatibility
at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1375)
at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1325)
at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1078)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader$ClassLoaderProxy.fetch4(RemoteClassLoader.java:742)
at hudson.remoting.RemoteClassLoader$ClassLoaderProxy.fetch3(RemoteClassLoader.java:784)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1170.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.perform(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:300)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
at     jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Build step 'Upload to Testflight' marked build as failure
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed with support team, the Jenkins needed to be restarted for the plugin updates to take effect. This fixed this issue.